# Preferred OS for hosting Tomcat servlet container

Tags: tomcat, hosting, operating-system

I know that I'm taking a risk, pitting the differing OS religions against each other, but I would like professional opinions about hosting a servlet container.  In my case the container is set, we will be using Tomcat.  But what is in question is the hosting operating system.  We have administrators experienced in Windows Server 2003.  We have developers experienced in Solaris, OSX, and Linux.  There is no warring between these groups, just a question of who will ramp up through the learning curve necessary to use the OS that they are unfamiliar with.  So given all the cooperative spirit, we are struggling with how to find the most efficient path.

Comment: I cross posted it there and on Super User as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most efficient thing would be to host it on the same platform you are developing the code on. If you are developing on Windows, host on Windows. If you are developing on Linux, host Linux.

Doing it that way will eliminate a whole slew of potential cross-platform related bugs when you go from development to production, and it will make it so any extraneous utility scripts you write for production can work in the development environment, and vice-versa.

Comment: We have developers using linux, OSX, and Windows.  Team lead is a OSX/linux user.

Comment: If you deploy on Solaris, do you develop on Solaris? No, you develop on a x386 machine and you just test it on Solaris at some time. No problem with that.

Comment: I'm agreed with the potential issues using different OS.  But not agree with the fact to choose the same platform for development and production. Production answer to production requirement (Cost / legacy / hardware / performance etc...) , Development answer to development requirements (Graphical environment, low cost, easy share-able, debug-able etc...) Without counting intermediate platform ,as Factory Test platform , before acceptance platform .. etc .

Answer (score 0):

Can't give you a scientific breakdown but it may not matter that much which one you choose. We use Linux to host Tomcat and have never had a problem. It may come down to who is going to maintain the server. Since it might be the administrator then go with what the admin is comfortable with. I don't think the developers have to worry too much about the platform.

I work on a Windows workstation but deploy to a Linux server. It is mostly trouble free.

Update: But I agree with @Spike Williams though about avoiding the headache of the cross platform bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly recommend Ubuntu Linux for simple reasons.

You can get a well-performing Tomcat plus your favorite database with Ubuntu 12.04 on a box with only 1GB Ram and 2 cores.

Java (OpenJdk) and Tomcat come prepackaged and are installed as easy as:

> sudo apt-get install default-jre tomcat7

If you install the tomcat6-user or tomcat7-user package, you can easily create multiple instances of Tomcat with the provided *tomcat7-instance-create* script.

You will probably use an Apache httpd as proxy in front of Tomcat. This is also easily installed.

With Windows you would need to find the right versions of each of these packages, and install them manually, one-by-one.

With Ubuntu you would only need to issue one single command:

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install default-jre tomcat7 apache2 postgresql